# Unable to open app in iPhone 5 after debugging using xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7, terminate

I am developing an app based on Images. I am at basic level,  I am debugging app using xcode 7.2.1 in iPhone 5 (iOS 9.2.1). Initially, I able to run app in mobile. Later after one week I started developing app further. Now, my app closes automatically within 1 to 2 seconds after tapping (opening).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to view the crash log connect your device, open `XCode -> Window -> Devices -> Select you device -> View device logs`. You'll get your crash logs there

Answer (score 0):

Your App is crashing, check debugger's output to see which code is crashing your app.

Comment: I am not getting any crashing or "unfortunately your app stopped" information. When I touch the icon it's opening for 1  second and closes automatically. Later, i double clicked the home button to open the background apps. I see my app in background but still i can't open it.

Comment: "unfortunately your app stopped" is not an iOS message. It's an Android message. If the app closes in iOS then it's a crash. You won't get any message at all.

Comment: You are right . i am not getting any message in ios. My is closing after tapping. I didn't find any solution. If you have any suggestions please give me.